# Filter map reduce to records that match a different collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to figure out an elegant way to do the following in mongo / python: I have two collections: one containing a list of people and attributes and one containing a subset of people that is a 'population subset'. I want to run a map reduce job to calculate some aggregate stats on the large list but only using names of people that appear in the population sample. Here is an example set of records:

```
master_list: [{ Name: Jim }, { Age: 24}
              { Name: Bill}, { Age: 38}
              { Name: Mary}, { Age: 55}]

subset : [{ Name: Jim}
          { Name: Mary}]
```

The idea is to calculate an average of age but only using two of the three records in the master_list, as listed in subset. I am aware that map_reduce in mongo supports a query parameter, but not clear what the best way to deal with the above is given the no joining. One option is for me to preprocess master_list and create an attribute 'include' to flag which records to use, and then operate on that in map_reduce filter. Seems kludgy though and creates a permanent flag in my database which is annoying for various reasons.

**UPDATE**

After reading suggestions to embed list in query I was able to get what I needed with the below

```
map_reduce(mapper, reducer, out = {'merge': 'Stats'}, 
           finalize = finalizer, scope = {'atts': f},
           query = {'Name' : { '$in' : pop }})
```

Where pop is a python list of names. Thanks!

Comment: how big is the subset collection?

Comment: subset is small, about 1500-2000 names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this in MongoDB.

1. If your subsets are fairly small, you can just do a query on subset to find all members and use the result of that query as an initial [query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) to a map-reduce call.
2. However, if you have very large subsets, this may not be possible. What you can do then, is to [simulate a join using two map-reduce calls](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/) with the 'reduce' output option to reduce into the same target collection. This will create an intermediate collection where the documents look something like this:

   ```
   {Name: Jim, Age: 24, inSubset: true}
   {Name: Bill, Age: 38, inSubset: false}
   {Name: Mary, Age: 55, inSubset: true}
   ```

   Finally, you can execute a third map reduce on this intermediate collection to average over all the documents that have `inSubset: true`.

Here is the code for the 2. option (the three map-reduces) in Python, using the pymongo driver:

```
from pymongo import Connection
from bson import ObjectId, Code

con = Connection(port=30000)  # add host/port here if different from default
db = con['test']    # or the database name you are using

# insert documents
db.master.insert({'_id': ObjectId(), 'Name': 'Jim', 'Age': 24})
db.master.insert({'_id': ObjectId(), 'Name': 'Bill', 'Age': 38})
db.master.insert({'_id': ObjectId(), 'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 55})

db.subset.insert({'_id': ObjectId(), 'Name': 'Jim'})
db.subset.insert({'_id': ObjectId(), 'Name': 'Mary'})

# map function for master collection
mapf_master = Code(""" function () {
    emit(this.Name, {'age': this.Age, 'inSubset': false});
} """)

# map function for subset collection
mapf_subset = Code(""" function() {
    emit(this.Name, {'age': 0, 'inSubset': true});
} """)

# reduce function for both master and subset
reducef = Code(""" function(key, values) {
    var result = {'age': 0, 'inSubset': false};

    values.forEach( function(value) {
        result.age += value.age;
        result.inSubset = result.inSubset || value.inSubset;
    });

    return result;
} """)

# call map-reduce on master and subset (simulates a join)
db.master.map_reduce(mapf_master, reducef, out={'reduce': 'join'})
db.subset.map_reduce(mapf_subset, reducef, out={'reduce': 'join'})


# final map function for third map-reduce call
mapf_final = Code(""" function() {
    if (this.value.inSubset) {
        emit('total', {'age': this.value.age, 'count': 1});
    }
} """)

# final reduce function for third map-reduce call
reducef_final = Code(""" function(key, values) {
    var result = {'age': 0, 'count': 0};

    values.forEach( function(value) {
        result.age += value.age;
        result.count += value.count;
    });

    return result;
} """)


# final finalize function, calculates the average
finalizef_final = Code(""" function(key, value) {
    if (value.count > 0) {
        value.averageAge = value.age / value.count;
    }
    return value;
} """)


# call final map-reduce 
db.join.map_reduce(mapf_final, reducef_final, finalize=finalizef_final, out={'merge': 'result'})
```

The result collection looks like this (queried from the mongo shell):

```
> db.result.find()
{ "_id" : "total", "value" : { "age" : 79, "count" : 2, "averageAge" : 39.5 } }
```

and the final average is stored in the value.averageAge field.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with option 1 as my subset is on the order of 1500-2000 names. Is that size what you were thinking is appropriate, and if so would you be so kind as to provide an example of how to effectively pass it into map reduce call?

Comment: I think your list sizes should work for option 1--it will be much faster than option 2 for small subsets. You might want to specify just the key fields you need to match with the main collection, so that you don't get any extra stuff back in the query (if there is any extra stuff).